# Setting Up Navigation Stack with only Odomtery

Tags: imu, navigation, odometry, gps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to set up the navigation stack on a robot possessing only odometry devices (wheel encoder, IMU, and GPS, published to `/odom /imu /gps`). No camera/laser. The robot is also using `robot_state_publisher` to publish the transformations between robot parts. The tree looks like this:

`/base_footprint` --> `/base_link` --> `/imu` `/gps` `/front_left_wheel_link` `/front_right_wheel_link` ...

If I want to use only odometry sources  (wheel encoder, IMU, and GPS) to navigate the robot, it seems the only frame transformation that needs to be done is `/map` --> `/odom` --> `/base_footprint`. I was wondering if this should be done manually or navigation stack (amcl localization?) is taking care of these two transformations?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191040/setting-up-navigation-stack-with-only-odomtery/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-08-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-08-24**:
Can I ask you how do you get information from /imu /gps and /odom the move your base_link?
In the tutorial about setting up the navigation stack I didn t find any example.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without a laser, you won't be able to use amcl. You should be able to use http://wiki.ros.org/fake_localization to use the odometry alone, however, given that odometry is going to drift, you'll likely get lost in your map.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-08-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can fuse all those sources together using a state estimation package like [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) or [robot_pose_ekf](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_pose_ekf). Depending on your GPS, there will likely be some extra effort required to get its data integrated. Those nodes will generate a odom->base_link transform for you.

However, if you really want to follow the ROS spec (particularly [REP-105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html)), you'll need to maintain all three frames (map, odom, and base_link), and only fuse GPS data with the estimate in the map frame. I'm in the process of updating robot_localization to better support this.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-08-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1